# BinarySearch for all occurrences?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can I search for all occurrences of a value in an array using `BinarySearch`? The default `TArray.BinarySearch` in `System.Generics.Collections` only returns one index.

Example Array:

A = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9];

Answer (score 3):

A binary search assumes you already have your array sorted, so any other matching elements would be clustered around the matching element returned by `BinarySearch`. The Delphi XE5 helps notes that

> If there is more than one element in the array equal to Item, the index of the first match is returned in FoundIndex. This is the index of any of the matching items, not necessarily of the first item."

This suggests that you'll need to run a search both forward and backward in the array to get all matching elements.

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm that will return an array of indexes of found matches.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand -- my answer included a sort of algorithm, but indeed I did not go into details. The idea is that you run BinarySearch() and if an index is returned, you run a linear search forward (i++) starting from that index until you either find an element that is _not_ the searched value, or you hit the end of the array. You also do the same backward (i--). You also add the indexes of all elements you encounter along the way that contain the value you looked for into a result array. Does this help?

Comment: Two binary searches are faster than binary search + sequential.

Comment: @user3764855: You don't need an array of indexes. Since all values with the same value will be consecutive, you only need to find the start and the end index of the range where they are. You start with a binary search to find one of them, and then search backward and forward sequentially until you found different values. This can NOT be done with a binary search, since all values are the same.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis What are you talking about? http://pastebin.com/mTzrZf15 How come it works for me?

Comment: @user3764855: Using your example, let's say we look for the value "3" and it comes back with the index 3 (assuming a 0-based index). All you need to do search forward and backward sequentially from that index. I don't see how a binary search for e.g. a part of the result set will be faster.

Comment: Hard to tell why it works for you. Your snippet is not a SSCCE, so I can't verify it. Some of the functions and variables used are not explained. It probably depends on your data too, for instance.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis This was ported from `C++` algorithm. So YES you CAN use BinarySearch for last index.

Comment: @PeterK O(n) vs O(Log(n))

Comment: Yes, you can, but it would probably just degrade to a linear search anyway, just with more overhead. It should be tested with a much larger set of numbers. But you want the *first* and the *last* index, right?

Comment: @user3764855: As I said, it would probably have more overhead than a linear search. Then your O(log(n)) doesn't help you much. The linear search is probably faster. But to actually be sure, you'll have to profile it, with a big variety of inputs , instead of theorizing.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis For 100000 records? Sequential would do you no good.

Comment: @user3764855: Well, not unless you have an array if identical elements. In any case, there's no reason why you couldn't use binary search on either side of the indexes and keep O(Log(n)), but you should look an element just 1 unit less, or just 1 unit greater than the value to look for. Even if the value is not present, a binary search-like algorithm will find the boundary for you.

Comment: @PeterK No you find the start index and last index with binary search.

Comment: @user3764855: Let me elaborate on my response. Binary search can actually find the value _nearest or equal_ to the one you looking for.  It's just normally we either return an index or "not found". After all the slicing done by binary search, the single value you have can be may be equal or not, but surely it will be the value nearest to the searched value. Using this property of the algorithm, you can search both side of your index and use binary search to find the the nearest value that is not equal to the searched value. The index of this item will mark the boundary of your range.

Comment: @user3764855: No, you cannot depend on two binary searches to return the first and last indexes. If the data doesn't change, and the center is dependent on the size, the search would start at the same place every time and find the same index every time. You *have* to start at the index and inspect previous and successive items to find the first and last index values, despite your opinion that it isn't so. (And why did you ask here if you simply intend to argue about the answers?)

Comment: @user is quite right that binary search can be used to find first match, or find last match.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [This](http://pastebin.com/7aC1JiGX) seems to work fine. Could it be done another way? Or is this good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain the problem a bit more to you. The difference between a sequential search and a binary search once you have found an index depends on the type of data you expect to find. The 10000 elements is not relevant, how many different values of the item you are searching for is. For example, if I had a list of 10000 elements consisting of only 1,2,3,4 and 5. We are talking about a situation where there could be thousands of each value and a series of subsequent binary searches would be preferable. If the values could range from 1 to 1000000, we are far less likely to have duplicates and a binary search followed by a sequential search in both directions is the best approach.

For the binary and then sequential approach, the algorithm to find the start and end index would be the following:

1. Find the index using a binary search.
2. Search left to find the first index using a sequential search.
3. Search right to find the last index using a sequential search.

If you wanted to use binary searches then you would need to switch your approach and do a series of recursive searches until you find the start and finish.

1. Find the index using a binary search.
2. Binary search 1..(index-1) for the value.
3. If you find the value then you will need to search again between 1 and newindex-1.
4. You will need to repeat this search until you don't find the value any more.
5. Binary search (index+1)..end for the value.
6. If you find the value then you will need to search again between newindex+1 and end.
7. You will need to repeat this search until you don't find the value any more.

A code example would look a bit like this. This code is for a binary search that exits when it first finds a match.

```
function GetIndexes(const aSearch: TSearchIntegers; const aValue: Integer; var aStartIndex, aEndIndex: Integer): Boolean;
var
  foundIndex: Integer;
  lookFor: Integer;
begin
  if BinarySearch(aSearch, aValue, foundIndex) then
  begin
    Result := True;
    lookFor := foundIndex;
    repeat
      aStartIndex := lookFor;
    until not BinarySearch(aSearch, aValue, lookFor, TComparer<Integer>.Default, 1, aStartIndex - 1);
    lookFor := foundIndex;
    repeat
      aEndIndex := lookFor;
    until not BinarySearch(aSearch, aValue, lookFor, TComparer<Integer>.Default, aEndIndex + 1, High(aSearch) - aEndIndex);
  end
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

Ultimately, your data (which we don't have) will determine the best course of action for you.

Now to complicate things a bit. The variation of the binary search that Delphi is using in TArray.BinarySearch is one that doesn't end early when a match is found. It will always find the index of the first item as it doesn't exit the loop when it finds a match.

```
Result := False;
L := Index;
H := Index + Count - 1;
while L <= H do
begin
  mid := L + (H - L) shr 1;
  cmp := Comparer.Compare(Values[mid], Item);
  if cmp < 0 then
    L := mid + 1
  else
  begin
    H := mid - 1;
    if cmp = 0 then
      Result := True;  // <-- It doesn't end here
  end;
end;
```

That means that you have a bit of a penalty when you have a lot of identical values but it does have a nice side effect. You can do something like this to find what you are looking for:

```
function GetIndexes(const aSearch: TSearchIntegers; const aValue: Integer; var aStartIndex, aEndIndex: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if TArray.BinarySearch<Integer>(aSearch, aValue, aStartIndex) then
  begin
    TArray.BinarySearch<Integer>(aSearch, aValue+1, aEndIndex);
    if aSearch[aEndIndex] <> aValue then
      Dec(aEndIndex);
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

This works because the search also returns the index of the next value even if it doesn't find aValue + 1 in the array. The `if` statement at the end is to handle the case when our value is also the last value of the array.

This is dependent on the code for TArray.BinarySearch remaining as it is.

Comment: @user3764855 That appears to be fine. I didn't look at it in too much detail. It seems a bit like overkill when there is already code in the present implementation that does what you need (the last block). The only problem is that it may change in the future. It all depends what data you are expecting and how many duplicates you expect to find. It should work but if you never expect to have more than one or two duplicates then it's definitely overkill.