# Fast way to find each pair of values from list

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

For example I have retrieved random entry point and hash from some files

```
EP   |  Hash
25432|545676343 
25732|344284432 
93632|9432763432 
45432|194363432 
35433|345676325
15434|445676337 
35439|745676343
55437|243276342
85532|476263821
85532|156743832 
85532|626343633
85531|626343633
```

Let's said the list is very huge.

I **want** to put all the data in memory since they are only Cardinal/Integer data type.

What is the fast(est) way if I want to find EP = 85532 and Hash = 626343633. I don't think `for loop` is the answer.

Note:

- Hash will be calculated and searched if only EP has been found.
- No duplicate data
- Data can be sorted

Thanks.

Comment: Which delphi version?

Comment: But you have duplicate in your test data?

Comment: The value of each EP or each Hash can be same. But each line have to unique.

Comment: If you can sort the data then this question and my answer should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584992/binarysearch-for-all-occurrences

Comment: @Graymatter, at first I was also thinking your concept! Let me learn your code first.

Comment: I think your real problem is that you are too code oriented. This sort of problem is all about choosing the right algorithm. Once you've done that the code writes itself. Playing trial and error with bits of code pulled from here and there isn't the way forward. It's a common problem, seen over and over.

Comment: Is there a lowest possible EP? and a HIghest possible EP?  If so you could load the hashes into an `array[LowestEP .. HighestEP] of THashData` so that `MyArray[SomeEP]` yields the hash(es) you want

Comment: @Hugh Jones The lowest/highest value is unknown. According my data, lowest data is 4 digits, highest data is 7 digits.

Comment: in that case you could index your (see my answer below) array from 999 to 9999999

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you don't have a hashlist in Delphi. You could of course easily write one, but you could also just use a tDictonary

Have a look at this and see if it makes sense:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  List: TDictionary<TPair<Integer, Cardinal>, Integer>;
begin

  //Dummy data
  List := TDictionary<TPair<Integer, Cardinal>, Integer>.Create;

  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(25432, 545676343), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(25732, 344284432), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(93632, 9432763432), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(45432, 194363432), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(35433, 345676325), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(15434, 445676337), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(35439, 745676343), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(55437, 243276342), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(85532, 476263821), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(85532, 156743832), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(85532, 626343633), List.Count);
  List.Add(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(85531, 626343634), List.Count);

  //check if exists
  List.ContainsKey(TPair<Integer, Cardinal>.Create(85531, 626343634));

  //Free data
  FreeAndNil(List);
end;
```

Comment: `Hash will be calculated and searched if only EP has been found`. ' Your sample use EP and Hash at the same time. Hash will not be calculated if EP has not found because it will waste time to hash the file.

Comment: @alycia according to the question, there is a file on the disk containing both ep and hash

Comment: sorry but the order is program retrieves ep, if ep found on list, program retrieves hash, if hash found on list with same ep then bingo!

The structure of list is ep|hash

Comment: @alycia If you want us to know such details, then they need to be in the question. Otherwise people might write code that is of no use.

Comment: Sorry I think my `Hash will be calculated and searched if only EP has been found.` is clear.

Comment: I disagree. How can the same EP value yield multiple hashes? There's clearly more that you aren't telling us.

Comment: I am sorry if I don't think it is not necessary to tell. For example some files packed with INNO or NSIS will have same EP. The hash is calculated from the resource section therefore yield multiple hash.

Comment: It's almost as if you don't want to be helped.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample with a dictionary and an object that can both store and build the hash if needed.

```
program so_28337613;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Generics.Defaults;

type
  // data object
  THasher = class
  private
    FEP: Integer;
    FHasHash: Boolean;
    FHash: Cardinal;
    function GetHash: Cardinal;
  protected
    procedure BuildHash( out AHash: Cardinal );
  public
    constructor Create( const EP: Integer ); overload;
    constructor Create( const EP: Integer; const Hash: Cardinal ); overload;
    property EP: Integer read FEP;
    property Hash: Cardinal read GetHash;
  end;

  { THasher }

procedure THasher.BuildHash( out AHash: Cardinal );
begin
  Writeln( 'DEBUG: Building Hash' );
  AHash := FEP;
end;

constructor THasher.Create( const EP: Integer );
begin
  inherited Create;
  FEP := EP;
end;

constructor THasher.Create( const EP: Integer; const Hash: Cardinal );
begin
  Create( EP );
  FHash := Hash;
  FHasHash := True;
end;

function THasher.GetHash: Cardinal;
begin
  if not FHasHash
  then
    begin
      BuildHash( FHash );
      FHasHash := True;
    end;
  Result := FHash;
end;
```

---

```
procedure Test;
var
  LHashDict: TObjectDictionary<THasher, Boolean>;
  LSearchFor: THasher;
begin
  LSearchFor := nil;
  LHashDict := nil;
  try
    LHashDict := TObjectDictionary<THasher, Boolean>.Create(
      {Ownerships} [doOwnsKeys],
      {AEqualityComparer} TEqualityComparer<THasher>.Construct(
        {EqualityComparison} (
            function( const L, R: THasher ): Boolean
      begin
        Writeln( 'DEBUG: Compare' );
        Result := ( L.EP = R.EP ) and ( L.Hash = R.Hash );
      end ),
    {Hasher} (
      function( const I: THasher ): Integer
      begin
        Result := I.EP;
      end ) ) );

    // Add known hashes

    LHashDict.Add( THasher.Create( 1, 45 ), True );
    LHashDict.Add( THasher.Create( 2, 56 ), True );
    LHashDict.Add( THasher.Create( 3, 76 ), True );
    LHashDict.Add( THasher.Create( 4, 34 ), True );
    LHashDict.Add( THasher.Create( 5, 5 ), True );
    LHashDict.Add( THasher.Create( 6, 23 ), True );
    LHashDict.Add( THasher.Create( 7, 78 ), True );
    LHashDict.Add( THasher.Create( 8, 89 ), True );

    // Looking for an object with now unknown hash
    LSearchFor := THasher.Create( 5 );

    if LHashDict.ContainsKey( LSearchFor )
    then
      Writeln( 'GOTCHA' );

  finally
    LHashDict.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

```
begin
  try
    Test;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln( E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message );
  end;
  Readln;

end.
```

As the debug outputs state there is only one compare and one hash building.

Comment: Given that each EP can have multiple associated values I'd use EP as integer as my key. The value would be a structure that had all the info relating to that EP.

Comment: Got `GOTCHA` if the parameter is 5 or using two parameters, else false?

Comment: You can create the `THasher` with only EP or both EP and HASH. On comparison first EP is compared and if that match, then there is comparison between both Hash-Values. If the Hash-Values are not present, they are generated. If both match then `HashDict.ContainsKey` returns true otherwise false.

Comment: Also you can go the other way round. Add a lot of `THasher.Create( ep )` to the dictionary and then search for `THasher.Create( 5, 12345 )`. The Hash is only generated, if EP matches. And it will only be generated once.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your data has more structure than can currently be observed (it appears to be unordered), and you wish to perform only one lookup, then you won't be able to beat a linear search, even though it has O(n) complexity. All other options have at least that complexity for the first search.

If the data is ordered then you can efficiently search for multiple items by using binary search. If the data is not ordered then it is an O(n log n) operation to order it which is clearly expensive. However, once ordered then binary search is O(log n).

Another option is to populate a dictionary. The standard Delphi dictionary has O(1) lookup. However, once again it is expensive to form the dictionary. But if you have the choice between sorting and building a dictionary choose the latter since it should be both faster to build and perform lookups.

In summary:

- To perform a single lookup, or perhaps a very small number of lookups, use linear search.
- To perform many lookups, use a dictionary.

On the face of it, one would assume that EP is the key of your dictionary.   But you seem to have multiple pairs with the same EP. So I guess you need to have a complex value structure that contains all the information relating to one specific EP key.

Comment: I want to perform a lot of lookup. Yes the data can be ordered (or sorted?), but I need to find then first value, if found then continue find the second value. Is it possible to use BS? I'm googling dictionary now.

Comment: I didn't write any code, or give more detail, because I still don't understand the precise details of your problem. That's why I kept it general.

Comment: My program calculates ep value of a file. If the ep value found on the list then program continue calculate hash value of the file. If the hash value with same ep value found on the list then it's done.  I can use binary search If the data is single value but this is pairs.

Comment: I've given a broad answer to the question you asked. I can't accept the question being asked in comments. You need to do a little bit of thinking now about your problem so that it is more clear in your head.

Answer (score 0):

While my next suggestion won't provide you best performance it is easy implementable and still offers quite good performance.

Now the easiest way to gain performance in your data searches would be splitting your data into organized groups.

Based on the fact that you claim that your primary search key is EP value and that it seems that EP value is a five digit number I would recommend creating 100 groups (separate arrays).

Each of these arrays will store part of your data in a way like so:
First array all item that have EP value between 0 and 1000
Second array all items that have EP value between 1001 and 2000
...

What this would allow is to use heuristic approach to lower the number of items that you need to iterate through by simply firs figuring out to which group that specific item belongs and then only iterating through the items in that particular group. And you can do this simply by dividing the EP value with 1000.

This greatly reduces the number of items you need to iterate through and doesn't require you to have all of the items perfectly sorted as it would be required for a binary search.

Also if there is a chance that there might be large number of different items that have same EP value you might want to create separate arrays for storing multiple items with same EP values in order to reduce the memory usage.

So for instance having separate array for storing let us say 100 items with EP value of 25759 would only require 32 bit for reference to the array and 100 times 32 bit (size of integer) which totals 3232 bits or 404 Bytes.
But storing these items as pairs would require 100 times 32 bit for cardinal part and 32 bit for integer part which totals to 6400 bits or 800 bytes.

Comment: There's a reason why we use binary search rather than ternary search, or denary search.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can put a number on how many of these data items you need then this could be an approach.  I can't imagine retrieval could be any faster but this is at the expense of memory ...

```
unit EZStore;

interface

const
  MAX_HASHES = 5;
  MAX_EPS = 10000000;

type
  THashArray = Array[0..MAX_HASHES -1] of Int64;

  TEZStore = class(TObject)
  private
    FData : Array[0..MAX_EPS - 1] of THashArray;
  public
    procedure Initialise();
    procedure Store(const AEP : Integer; const AHash : Int64);
    function Retrieve(const AEP : Integer) : THashArray;
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure TEZStore.Initialise;
begin
  FillChar(FData, MAX_HASHES * MAX_EPS, 0);
end;

function TEZStore.Retrieve(const AEP: Integer): THashArray;
begin
  Result := FData[AEP];
end;

procedure TEZStore.Store(const AEP: Integer; const AHash: Int64);
var
  ThisHashArray : THashArray;
  i : integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  ThisHashArray := FData[AEP];

  while(FData[AEP][i] <> 0) do begin
    Inc(i);
    if (i > MAX_HASHES - 1) then
      raise Exception.Create(Format('The maximum of %d hashes per entry point has been exceeded', [MAX_HASHES]));
  end;

  FData[AEP][i] := AHash;
end;

end.
```